# Add scrollbars to kendo.alert dialog box

Tags: kendo-ui, alert

I'm trying to use the kendo.alert function instead of the normal javascript alert - but whenever I pass in a lot of text (e.g. lots of paragraphs with linefeeds) the alert box grows past the height of the current window, meaning you can only see the bottom part of the text plus the OK button. Is there a way to enable scrollbars on kendo.alert so you can see all lines?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some CSS to force scrollbars:

```
.k-alert {
    max-width: 50%; 
}

.k-alert .k-content{
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/YvqdaZ)**

You could also use JavaScript to calculate available screen height and then set the content max-height accordingly.

Alternatively, use the full kendo dialog and set the maxHeight property:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog/configuration/maxheight